# How do I get the return variable from a function inside another function

Tags: php, oop

Using an [Excel library](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import#chunk), how do I make function `check_stuff` return `false` when needed? As of right now, `$this->check_stuff($path)` always returns `true`. Keep in mind that I cannot modify class `Excel`.

```
private function check_stuff($path) {
    Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(250, function($results) {
    // check something
        return false;
    });

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to import it in the anonymous function:

```
private function check_stuff($path) {

    $result = true;
    Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(250, function($results) use (&$result) {
        // check something
        $result = false;
    });

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I didn't know I could do that in PHP. Hope this can help someone in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @user173457 yes you could use that to pass inside an anonymous function. glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
private function check_stuff($path) {
  return Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(250, function($results) {
    // check something
    return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: First thing I tried. That function call always returns `null`.